# Virtualbox Appliance: Maintain same Private IP as used with Vagrant

Tags: virtualbox, ip-address, vagrant, virtual-appliances

I have an OVA which I created in conjunction with Vagrant.  I want to distribute the OVA, but when people start it up I want to have the same Private IP address assigned by Vagrant.  So far I've had no luck.

Any recommendations on how to export an OVA appliance and have it maintain the same private ip address as used during vm creation?

Thanks many times over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't.

You could configure the guest to use a manually set IP address, but you can't be sure that it will work for every user, nor even for any of them.

You can't predict what sort of network environment your appliance will be used in. It's even likely that most people who use your appliance won't use VirtualBox at all, since it's only suitable for consumer and (sometimes) developer use.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Sounds like a well justified response.

Comment: Really just want to achieve a constant IP address if user turns off VM and restarts, I can't have the IP change. Any recommendations on that?

Comment: @bcollins That's not something _you_ need to worry about unless your application depends on the IP address for some reason. And then, you should detect it, or better yet, fix the application.